# Cellular Automata rendering

Tags: java, rendering

I am developing a Java game in my free time. The world/map consists of different kinds of cells: wood, snow, water, etc. The player can walk around and manipulate the terrain/cells with tools.

[image: Picture of the game]

### Rendering and updating

The world in this game is based on cells. One cell is 4x4 pixels. All of the cells are stored in a 2D array. The size of the world is currently 1920x3 pixels wide and 1080x3 pixels high. This means that my world contains 1 555 200 cells.

In order to update and render this many cells, I divided the world into 9 chunks (3x3) and divided each chunk into 100 subchunks (10x10). It can be represented graphically like this:

[image: Chunks and subchunks drawing]

The update and render method loops through the chunks and checks if a chunk is active. If so, it loops through the subchunks. If a subchunk is active, the cells are updated and rendered.

The subchunks are active if:

1. The player is nearby.
2. A cell is moving or is active in any way.

### How rendering is done

For rendering, I used a canvas that is added to a frame. The cells are all drawn to a `volatileImage`. Some pseudo code:

```
GraphicsConfiguration gc = canvas.getGraphicsConfiguration();
VolatileImage vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
Graphics g = vImage.getGraphics()
for() {
    g.fillRect()
}
```

### The problem

Since only active subchunks are rendered, I cannot change the position or translate cells complementary to the player's movement. For now, I set the canvas size equal to the size of the world, and when the player moves I just translate the entire image (then I don't need to redraw any of the dormant subchunks). However, this limits the size of my world to the max size of a canvas... So I tried to center the player's position at the center of the screen and moving the cells' position when the player moves, but of course the graphics smear the screen since they are not redrawn...

### Ideas for solutions

1. Create one image/canvas per chunk? or 3x3 chunks? I think this solution would technically work, but I don't like it.
2. Faster rendering... Well of course. But maybe there are faster ways of rendering pixels/cells so that I can render all the cells displayed on the screen? Maybe I have to take a look at JOGL or something?
3. When the player reaches the edge of the canvas I move the canvas and redraw everything. This will produce a lag spike like no other and is probably not enjoyable for the user.

I am kind of stumped. Am I missing something?

I hope that I explained everything clearly. Thank you for your time.